# Running NUnit tests in TeamCity 6.5.X with NUnit addins

Tags: unit-testing, testing, nunit, teamcity

We are using TeamCity 6.5.1 to manage the compilation, testing and deployment of our builds.  Up until now we have been using the NUnit Build Runner from TeamCity to run our tests with NUnit 2.5.8 and had great success.

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD65/NUnit

All of our tests are written in C# and .Net 4.0 using Visual Studio 2010.  The test projects are compiled into an assembly that we reference through the TeamCity interface.

Now we are adding in a new test project for UI tests that require a custom NUnit addin that we developed to extend the native NUnit functionality.  When running the tests in a local development environment with NUnit 2.5.8 installed we are able to place the custom addin in the NUnit addins directory.  When NUnit is loaded our addin is picked up automatically.

C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.5.8\bin\net-2.0\addins

Using the NUnit Build Runner in TeamCity 6.5.1 we cannot see of a way to install our addin.  Unlike the native installation of NUnit, TeamCity does not appear to pick up an addin just by placing it inside a sub directory of the NUnit installation.

Does anyone know of a way to install/use an addin using the NUnit Build Runner?  Existing documentation discusses the NUnit command line console runner which we are not using.  We are using the NUnit Build Runner as the method to run all of our tests so it would be most ideal if we could maintain a standard testing mechanism.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried just to put this Add-in into the Visual Studio tests project as reference/resource specifying build action as "Copy To Output" and see whether it would be picked up by TeamCity when placed along with a test assembly which uses this addin

Comment: Why aren't you willing to use the NUnit command line tool? It is surely a standard testing mechanism. It is easy to import the test results into Temacity as well. When the "out of the box" approach does not hold, it is perfectly fine to use a custom one...

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to solve the same problem.
As I found out TeamCity uses its assembly Nunit.
Therefore there is no possibility of expansion.  You can use the command line to run tests via Nunit. And TeamCity use step "Build Failure Conditions"  for reading logs and view the results.